# HyperlinkButton in C# XAMARIN.FORMS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to create Label with click possibility like in WIN phone xaml

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="My Text to click"/>
```

Is there a possibility to do it in Xamarin.Forms?

I found this but is not the same:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HyperLinkLabel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest using `GestureRecognizers` and adding a `Tap Gesture` to a label. [Ref: here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/gestures/#Adding_a_Gesture_Recognizer)

```
var label = new Label()
{
  Text="My Hyperlink"
};
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

`GestureRecognizer` is a public property on the `View` class which `Label` inherits from. See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.View/)

Comment: This may not be accessible and show up for users of eg Voiceover.

Answer (score 22):

I'd take a much more standard approach and use a `Button`. Just set the background to match your app background and remove the border. Then there's no need for extra `TapGestureRecongniser` code. (Pseudo Code below:)

Xaml:

```
<Button Text="Click Me!" Background= "YourAppBackground" BorderWidth="0" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //Open your link in here
}
```

Comment: How can I redirect to a page in this method ?

Comment: I mean, creating the event handler is trivial and obvious, but how do you actually open a link?

Answer (score 4):

XAML code would be as follows:

```
<Label
    Text="My Text to click"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" >

    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="OnLabelTapped"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Note: By default, `NumberOfTapsRequired` is 1.

Then in your `.cs` file, add the method `OnLabelTapped`.

```
public void OnLabelTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Your code here
    // Example:
    // DisplayAlert("Message", "You clicked on the label", "OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either use Button Clicked or TapGestureRecognizer. 
If you want to redirect to a site you can use WebView. 
If you want to direct to your  own Native page:
If you are using NavigationPage, you can use 
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());
If your not using NavigationPage and would like to change MainPage:
    App.Current.MainPage = new MyContentPage();

Answer (score 0):

This is a class I use to have a label act as a link:

```
public class SimpleLinkLabel : Label
{
    public SimpleLinkLabel(Uri uri, string labelText = null)
    {
        Text = labelText ?? uri.ToString();
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = new Command(() => Device.OpenUri(uri)) });
    }
}
```

For more options, this answer about [creating a hyperlink in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232066/865643) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I do this --> create the following class:

```
public class ButtonAsLink : Button
{
    public ButtonAsLink()
    {
        this.TextColor = Color.Blue;
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.BorderWidth = 0;
    }
}
```

Then everywhere you need to create a link button use this:

```
SendButton = new ButtonAsLink()
        {
            Text = "Send Logs...",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
```

Comment: Using this, will the default button styles still apply on Windows devices, for example the background and border changes on hover? Possible to override those in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want stylish the button (make it like hyperlink - with underline) you would like to implement the custom renderer:

Add this to xamarin.project

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xamarin.Mobile.Controls
{
    public class HyperlinkButton : Button
    {
        public HyperlinkButton()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And implementation the renderer to IOS project:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using xamarin.Mobile.IOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(xamarin.Mobile.Controls.HyperlinkButton), typeof(HyperlinkButtonRenderer))]
namespace xamarin.Mobile.IOS
{
    public class HyperlinkButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                //Set attribute for underlineing information links
                var underlineAttr = new UIStringAttributes { UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single };
                Control.SetAttributedTitle(new NSAttributedString(Control.CurrentTitle, underlineAttr), UIControlState.Normal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added renderer for iOS only. If you want to support another versions - you have to add renderers to this platforms.

And use it at xcml like this:

```
<ContentPage ...
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:xamarin.Mobile.Controls">

<control:HyperlinkButton Text="Cancel" Clicked="CancelClicked"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to KidCode answer with actual code for opening the browser link

Xaml View:

```
<Button Text="Go Google" Clicked="GoGoogle" />
```

Code behind:

```
    void GoGoogle(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
       Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com");
    }
```